# Write onScroll event to div in ZK

Tags: html, zk

I need an way to write onScroll event to DIV in ZK. If I use native div tag I can do it,  but I want to do it for an div tag in ZUL

Comment: You want to have a server side event(Java event) or client side event (JavaSCript event) ?

Comment: @TonyQ Java Event i.e Server side.

Answer (score 0):

`Events.sendEvent("yourEventName", targetComponent, data)` or `Events.postEvent()`